# Using TextWriter to write text files with parametric fileName

Tags: c#, file, text, textwriter

I have to write some text on text file using `TextWriter`.

My code is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<int> _list_1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   List<int> _list_2 = new List<int>() { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
   var _year = 2005;
   var _root = @"C:\Users\~\Results";
   var _path = Path.Combine(_root, _year.ToString());
   var _testFile = _year.ToString() + " - IntegerLists.txt";
   _path = Path.Combine(_root, _year.ToString());

   if (!Directory.Exists(_path))
   {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(_path);
   }

   Console.WriteLine("Writing lists on text file...");
   TextWriter _tw = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(_path, _testFile));

   for ( int _i = 0; _i < _list_1.Count; _i++ )
   {
      _tw.WriteLine("List - 1 : {0}, List - 2 : = {1}", _list_1[_i], _list_2[_i]);
   }

   Console.WriteLine("Lists have been written on text file.");
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It created the text file at specified path but there are no values in that text file.  I got an empty file.

How to write text using `TextWriter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either `Dispose` or call `Flush` on the `TextWriter` instance. (See [File.CreateText Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx))